# why the input is incompatible with the layer model_16?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, layer, max-pooling

I'm training my model in order to classify sleep stages , after extracting features from my signal I collected the features(X) in a DataFrame with shape(335,48) , and y (labels) in shape of (335,)

this is my code :

```
def get_base_model():
    inp = Input(shape=(335,48))
    img_1 = Convolution1D(16, kernel_size=5, activation=activations.relu, padding="valid")(inp)
    img_1 = Convolution1D(16, kernel_size=5, activation=activations.relu, padding="valid")(img_1)
    img_1 = MaxPool1D(pool_size=2)(img_1)
    img_1 = SpatialDropout1D(rate=0.01)(img_1)
    img_1 = Convolution1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation=activations.relu, padding="valid")(img_1)
    img_1 = Convolution1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation=activations.relu, padding="valid")(img_1)
    img_1 = MaxPool1D(pool_size=2)(img_1)
    img_1 = SpatialDropout1D(rate=0.01)(img_1)
    img_1 = Convolution1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation=activations.relu, padding="valid")(img_1)
    img_1 = Convolution1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation=activations.relu, padding="valid")(img_1)
    img_1 = MaxPool1D(pool_size=2)(img_1)
    img_1 = SpatialDropout1D(rate=0.01)(img_1)
    img_1 = Convolution1D(256, kernel_size=3, activation=activations.relu, padding="valid")(img_1)
    img_1 = Convolution1D(256, kernel_size=3, activation=activations.relu, padding="valid")(img_1)
    img_1 = GlobalMaxPool1D()(img_1)
    img_1 = Dropout(rate=0.01)(img_1)

    dense_1 = Dropout(0.01)(Dense(64, activation=activations.relu, name="dense_1")(img_1))

    base_model = models.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=dense_1)
    opt = optimizers.Adam(0.001)

    base_model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['acc'])
    model.summary()
    return base_model
model=get_base_model()

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(Xtest, ytest, verbose=0) 
model.fit(X,y)
print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)
```

I got the error :
Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_16: expected shape=(None, 335, 48), found shape=(None, 48)

Comment: @AkshaySehgal thank you for answering me , here s the entire code can you please guide me : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17W58QZyJrSp0YiMm6ZFsHQ_f5eGzC_-Y

Answer (score 0):

Here are things you need to do.

1. As input, you don't need to specify `(355, 48)` as input size. The first channel is automatically set to `none`. Setting it to `(48,)` will allow you to pass 48 features for each sample.
2. Conv1D expects a 2D tensor, so use `layers.Reshape` to change `(48,)` to `(48,1)`
3. The large number of maxpools cause some issues, so I have removed some conv1d blocks and updated the kernel sizes so that you don't run out of features to convolve over.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras import activations, losses, optimizers, models

def get_base_model():
    inp = Input(shape=(48,))
    x = Reshape((-1,1))(inp)
    img_1 = Convolution1D(16, kernel_size=3, activation=activations.relu, padding="valid")(x)
    img_1 = Convolution1D(16, kernel_size=3, activation=activations.relu, padding="valid")(img_1)
    img_1 = MaxPool1D(pool_size=2)(img_1)
    img_1 = SpatialDropout1D(rate=0.01)(img_1)
    img_1 = Convolution1D(32, kernel_size=2, activation=activations.relu, padding="valid")(img_1)
    img_1 = Convolution1D(32, kernel_size=2, activation=activations.relu, padding="valid")(img_1)
    img_1 = MaxPool1D(pool_size=2)(img_1)
    img_1 = SpatialDropout1D(rate=0.01)(img_1)
    img_1 = Convolution1D(256, kernel_size=3, activation=activations.relu, padding="valid")(img_1)
    img_1 = Convolution1D(256, kernel_size=3, activation=activations.relu, padding="valid")(img_1)
    img_1 = GlobalMaxPool1D()(img_1)
    img_1 = Dropout(rate=0.01)(img_1)

    dense_1 = Dropout(0.01)(Dense(64, activation=activations.relu, name="dense_1")(img_1))

    base_model = models.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=dense_1)
    opt = optimizers.Adam(0.001)

    base_model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['acc'])
    model.summary()
    return base_model

model = get_base_model()

X = np.random.random((335, 48))
y = np.random.random((335,))

model.fit(X, y, epochs=4)
```

```
Model: "functional_194"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_158 (InputLayer)       [(None, 48)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_48 (Reshape)         (None, 48, 1)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_57 (Conv1D)           (None, 46, 16)            64        
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_58 (Conv1D)           (None, 44, 16)            784       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_21 (MaxPooling (None, 22, 16)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
spatial_dropout1d_21 (Spatia (None, 22, 16)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_59 (Conv1D)           (None, 21, 32)            1056      
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_60 (Conv1D)           (None, 20, 32)            2080      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_22 (MaxPooling (None, 10, 32)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
spatial_dropout1d_22 (Spatia (None, 10, 32)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_61 (Conv1D)           (None, 8, 256)            24832     
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_62 (Conv1D)           (None, 6, 256)            196864    
_________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling1d_6 (Glob (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_12 (Dropout)         (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                16448     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_13 (Dropout)         (None, 64)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 242,128
Trainable params: 242,128
Non-trainable params: 0


Epoch 1/4
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: 8.6069 - acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/4
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 4.1998 - acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/4
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 4.1589 - acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/4
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 4.1820 - acc: 0.0000e+00
```

Comment: I got the error : name 'Reshape' is not defined

Comment: `from tensorflow.keras.layers import Reshape` Please import this. Updated my answer with the same.

Comment: Let me know if you are able to run the code now. Do mark the answer if you are able to else please update the question with the issue you are facing.

Comment: its compiling now , but why I receive 0 accuracy ?

Comment: That has to do with your data and not with your architecture. Maybe you are not using the right architecture for the right problem? I would advice starting with a simpler model with just dense layers instead of using a Conv nets.

Comment: Also, where is your model training? I only see a model evaluate. Where are you training the model? What is the shape of your X_train and y_train?

Comment: yes exactly , its a multi classification problem with 67 outputs u9

Comment: yes exactly , its a multi classification problem , I have 5 classes , each class present a sleep stage and containing 67 signals ,   (labels are W, R,N1,N2,N3) ,  I extracted features from all signals and created a label column , I mentioned the x train and y train in my code

Comment: So X only has 335 samples? Your total training data is only 335 rows?

Comment: X is the extracted features so it takes the shape (5*number of signals , number of extracted features ) =(5*67,48)=(335,48)

Comment: Yea i get that but 335 samples are not enough to train a model this complex! How many unique classes do you have in Y?

Comment: 5 classes : w , r , n1 , n2 ,  n3